# Transforming a plane to xy-plane

Tags: geometry

I have to rotate a plane to xy-plane. I have an arbitrary plane ax+by+cz+d=0. I tried using the transformation mentioned below to convert this plane to xy-plane but could not get what i expected. Does this transformation lead to the z-coordinate being 0 if the point lies in the plane ax+by+cz+d=0?

Emilio Novati (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/187568/emilio-novati), Transform a plane to the xy plane., URL (version: 2015-02-27): https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1167779

Edit: I was able to implement the transformation. There is a mistake in the calculation of unit vector(u1,u2,u3) perpendicular to v & k in above transformation.

Comment: Not necessarily that complicated. You only need to rotate about a line parallel to the intercept line $ax+by=0$.

Comment: Are you trying to rotate your plane so that it is parallel to the $x$-$y$ plane or also translate it so that they coincide? Either way, there is in general an infinite number of rotations that will accomplish this, so it doesn’t quite make sense to speak of “the transformation.” Rotating about the intersection of the two planes—i.e., “tilting” the original plane—is in some sense a minimal rotation that accomplishes this. There’s a much more straightforward way to construct any of these rotations, however, that doesn’t require coming up with a rotation angle (or sines/cosines of it) directly.

Comment: Well, straightforward for me, that is. It involves a cross product and a matrix multiplication or two.

Comment: You should note the error in the answer you were using in a comment.